# Как поменять корень ссылок с помощью htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день всем. Недавно столкнулся с проблемой. Есть сайт `site.ru` и я хочу в его каталоге `site.ru/game` положить второй сайт. Проблема в том, что ссылки второго сайта выглядят как `site.ru/news/` а нужно что бы были `site.ru/game/news/`, как это сделать с помощью htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сохранить ссылки:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^news(.*)$  /game/news$1
```

Если нужна переадресация:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^news(.*)$  /game/news$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. А как к всем ссылкам приделать в начале game, если неза что зацепиться?

Comment: @Alex а как вы определите, это ссылка на первый сайт или на второй?

Comment: Никак, я пытаюсь соединить 2 сайта.

Comment: @Alex так если вы сами не можете определить, то как сервер это сделает?

Comment: А по каталогу в котором находиться 2 сайт, никак нельзя поменять ссылки?

Comment: @Alex Задайте новый вопрос, подробно опишите проблему, как вы пытались ее решить, и что у вас не получилось. Комментарии на SO используются только для уточнений.